# can't display Openstreetmap

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I want to display a part of a OSM but i don't know what's the problem with my code, when I run it, the map didn't display:

No error appear but the map didn't only display! I work with eclipse and the emulator Google API 8!

here is my MainActivity code:

```
package com.formation.dsmap1;

import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapActivity;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
//import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
//import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
//import android.os.Environment;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {


//  @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MapView mapView = new MapView(this);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setEnabled(true);


//        mapView.setMapFile("/sdcard/essai.jpg");
//        setContentView(mapView); 


      mapView.setMapFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "essai.osm");
        setContentView(mapView); 

    } 

}
```

and my AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.formation.dsmap1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.formation.dsmap1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Just check if your Google API key is right? Second thing you are using Google Map v1 method which is already deprecated. So just use Google Map v2 instead of it. Also you didn't add Google API key in your manifest file.

Comment: I'm using a local openstreeetmap so I think that I don't need API Key? Don't I? And I would like to know if I can display a Map.osm? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this permission to your manifest and will be fine :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```